# Browsermob-Proxy - Problem to read XHR over SSL

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, chromium, browsermob-proxy

This is my setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
- Linux 4.19.66-v7+ (RaspbianGNU/Linux 9 (stretch))
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Browsermob-Proxy 2.1.4
- Chromium 72.0.3626.121
- ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.121
- Python 3.5.3

I would like to record the network traffic when I visit an https page. So far, it actually works quite well. The problem is, the content of the packages that browsermob proxy records are encrypted.

Here my code

```
import pprint
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from browsermobproxy import Server

# Source: https://github.com/ArturSpirin/YouTube-WebDriver-Tutorials/blob/master/proxy/BmpProxy.py
class ProxyManger:

    __BMP = "/usr/local/bin/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__server = Server(ProxyManger.__BMP, options={'port': 8089})
        self.__client = None

    def start_server(self):
        self.__server.start()
        return self.__server

    def start_client(self):
        self.__client = self.__server.create_proxy(params={"trustAllServers": "true"})
        return self.__client

    @property
    def client(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                return self.__client                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  @property
    def server(self):
        return self.__server

# set virtual dispaly
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start() 

# set browsermob-proxy
proxy = ProxyManger()                                                                                                                                                                                                                        server = proxy.start_server() 
client = proxy.start_client()
client.new_har(url)

# set chrome options 
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("--proxy-server={}".format(client.proxy))
opts.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")                                                                                                                                                                                           
opts.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
pprint.pprint(client.har)

browser.quit()
server.stop()
display.stop()
```

The code works quite well so far. I receive the packages i want.

The problem is the encrypted content. It is clear to me that the browsermob-proxy acts as a MITM and cannot read the contents of these packages due to the end-to-end encryption.

```
...
'content': {'comment': '',
                                               'encoding': 'base64',
                                               'mimeType': 'application/json',
                                               'size': 10493,
                                               'text': 'IUQHACBHdln10z6SWSgCD9DkLZ0OUL9H9+NwllhRXLaI+7nOI023mVdkr5uCJV115AeolXUwyJUgklGU8z/0tYu/n/iuQCnAQJIG8JwmwaOcwRRLTheZ8abRSDFM/gQTqc6nP03QiSiJ/ZuxVZTkH/6SKKpir/SsMAt5+RMiPU+eJ3fN+U8JBjguGdWoNCGCrSqOw9gBeKORKcY4Ek014310aXl3BUqBnJ01VqPyeaJQasKY1hxRkkYTfFGAefuYQ5pbF1588ghm1VDPrdoKB1lERMVl/j0Y2HWEt+tbdHYe3t9fCrtSN+5Nq++ejmp/pg9UUuyVF8FlWvJiA6YB'},
...
```

I run the Raspberry Pi headless. That means I only have access via ssh and no x. According to the github page of [Browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy), it is possible to add a [certificate](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/browsermob-core/src/main/resources/sslSupport/ca-certificate-rsa.cer) to my browser. 
According to some internet research, this usually works in chrome via the GUI.

After doing some more research, I found this:

https://github.com/ThomasLeister/root-certificate-deployment

I ran *linux-browser-import.sh*, but unfortunately this had no effect on that.

Where is my mistake? Does someone have a solution to my problem? How is it possible to read packages decrypted from an ssl connection?

Is there any other method known how I can read xhr packages?

Thanks,
Mike